# How can i make an array holding the walls

Tags: java, graphics, collision-detection

I need a simple do loop for my game but don't know how to create one.
I have a simple maze game.
I still need to add more walls
I was thinking of creating an array and calling the index of the array in the do loop to call the wall but i dont now how to do it
I was thinking that I could create a do loop instead of copying and pastinn the collision code 30 times.
My player needs to be reset to the beginning when it touches a wall

The player is s simple JLabel.My walls are also a JLabel.I'm using swing components for my game.

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
 * This class Holds the game pane that has the moving player. It also contains
 * the GamePane
 * 
 * @author 602052004
 *
 */

public class GamePane extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {// *change GamePane to GamePane
    // This is where the game screen is made and the player is created.

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JLabel player = new JLabel();
    //This is were the Jlabels for the walls are created
    JLabel wall1 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall2 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall3 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall4 = new JLabel();
    JLabel wall5 = new JLabel();

    int playerSpeed = 5;
    int FPS = 40;
    private final Set<Integer> keys = new HashSet<>();

    // The keys set holds the keys being pressed

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Open the GUI window
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Create a new object and
                // run its go() method
                new GamePane().go();
            }
        });
    }

    GamePane() {
        // Run the parent class constructor
        super();
        // Allow the panel to get focus
        setFocusable(true);
        // Don't let keys change the focus

    }

    /**
     * The frame that shows my game. It contains the game frame which holds my
     * JPanel GameStage and ButtonPane.
     */
    protected void go() {
        setLayout(new CardLayout());
        // Setup the window
        JFrame GameFrame = new JFrame();
        // Add this panel to the window
        GameFrame.setLayout(new CardLayout());
        GameFrame.add(this, "main");
        GameFrame.setContentPane(this);

        // Set's the window properties
        GameFrame.setTitle("main");
        GameFrame.setSize(800, 600);
        GameFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        GameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GameFrame.setVisible(true);
        GameFrame.add(new ButtonPane(GameFrame), "buttons");
        // Creates the new JPanel that will hold the game.
        JPanel gamestage = new JPanel();
        gamestage.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        GameFrame.add(gamestage, "game");
        gamestage.setLayout(null);
        // *Move the setup of the player and the timer under the walls
        // Get a sample of collisions going so that i can do it over the weekend
        // Setup the movable box
        player.setBounds(25, 25, 20, 20);
        player.setVisible(true);
        player.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        // Opaque makes the background visible
        player.setOpaque(true);

        // Setup the key listener
        addKeyListener(this);
        // Null layout allows moving objects!!!
        gamestage.add(player);
        // Set the timer
        Timer tm = new Timer(1000 / FPS, this);
        tm.start();

        wall1.setBounds(10, 15, 10, 480);
        wall1.setVisible(true);
        wall1.setBackground(Color.white);
        wall1.setOpaque(true);
        gamestage.add(wall1);

        wall2.setBounds(10, 10, 755, 10);
        wall2.setVisible(true);
        wall2.setBackground(Color.white);
        wall2.setOpaque(true);
        gamestage.add(wall2);
        // wall3.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        wall3.setBounds(10, 100, 100, 10);
        wall3.setVisible(true);
        wall3.setBackground(Color.white);
        wall3.setOpaque(true);
        gamestage.add(wall3);

        wall4.setBounds(100, 60, 10, 40);
        wall4.setVisible(true);
        wall4.setBackground(Color.white);
        wall4.setOpaque(true);
        gamestage.add(wall4);

        wall5.setBounds(70, 60, 35, 10);
        wall5.setVisible(true);
        wall5.setBackground(Color.white);
        wall5.setOpaque(true);
        gamestage.add(wall5);


    }

    public boolean areColliding(JLabel a, JLabel b) {
         return a.getBounds().intersects(b.getBounds());
         }



    /**
     * this method makes the player move. It takes the players speed and subtracts
     * or adds the player speed to the current position of the player. It also
     * figures out were the player is at currently aswell.
     * 
     * @param arg0
     */
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // Move up if W is pressed
        if (keys.contains(KeyEvent.VK_W)) {
            player.setLocation(player.getX(), player.getY() - playerSpeed);
        }
        // Move right if D is pressed
        if (keys.contains(KeyEvent.VK_D)) {
            player.setLocation(player.getX() + playerSpeed, player.getY());
        }
        // Move down if S is pressed
        if (keys.contains(KeyEvent.VK_S)) {
            player.setLocation(player.getX(), player.getY() + playerSpeed);
        }
        // Move left if A is pressed
        if (keys.contains(KeyEvent.VK_A)) {
            player.setLocation(player.getX() - playerSpeed, player.getY());
        }

         // Check for collisions
         if (areColliding(wall1, player)) {
         // Reposition the target
         int newX = (int) (25);
         int newY = (int) (25);
         player.setLocation(newX, newY);}
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // Add the key to the list
        // of pressed keys
        if (!keys.contains(e.getKeyCode())) {
            keys.add(e.getKeyCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // Remove the key from the
        // list of pressed keys
        keys.remove((Integer) e.getKeyCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

}
```

This is just for you to have a running main screen to go to when playing the game

```
/**
 * This pane contains the button and sets up the button pane
 */
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ButtonPane extends JPanel {

    private JButton startBTN;// Calls the JButton
    JFrame game;

    public ButtonPane(JFrame g) {
        game = g;
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        setBackground(Color.gray);// Sets the menu stages color blue
        startBTN = new JButton("Start");// Creates a new button
        add(startBTN);// Adds the button on the startStage

        startBTN.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (game.getContentPane().getLayout() instanceof CardLayout) {
                    CardLayout layout = (CardLayout) getParent().getLayout();
                    layout.show(game.getContentPane(), "game");

                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Before you go any further, I want you to go have a look at [the button on my screen wont switch me towards my game pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731112/the-button-on-my-screen-wont-switch-me-towards-my-game-pane/50731295#50731295) which attempts to provide a better understanding of how you can make `CardLayout` work for you, because right now, your code is spaghetti and makes it difficult to reason about

Comment: *"The player is s simple JLabel.My walls are also a JLabel.I'm using swing components for my game"* - I keep seeing this and I keep asking the same question - why? Swing components are complex components, with lots of overhead and management requirements. A simpler solution be to use a custom painting route, but that's just me.

Comment: To answer your question, place all the objects that the player can collide with in a `List`. On each movement of the player, loop over this list and use the [`Rectangle#contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#contains-java.awt.Rectangle-) and [`Rectangle#intersects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#intersects-java.awt.Rectangle-).  The rectangles are provided by the components `getBounds` method

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to place all the objects that the player can collide with in a `List`.

On each movement of the player, loop over this list and use the [`Rectangle#contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#contains-java.awt.Rectangle-) and [`Rectangle#intersects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#intersects-java.awt.Rectangle-) provided by the component's `getBounds` methods

Which might look something like this...

```
public class GamePane extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {// *change GamePane to GamePane

    private List<JComponent> collidableStuff;

    public GamePane() {
        collidableStuff = new ArrayList<>(25);
        //...
        wall1 = ...;
        wall2 = ...;
        wall3 = ...;
        wall4 = ...;
        wall5 = ...;
        // In fact, you could get rid of wall1-5 and just
        // use the list instead
        collidableStuff.add(wall1);
        collidableStuff.add(wall2);
        collidableStuff.add(wall3);
        collidableStuff.add(wall4);
        collidableStuff.add(wall5);
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //...
        player.setLocation(newX, newY);

        performCollisionDetection();
    }

    protected void performCollisionDetection() {
        Rectangle playerBounds = player.getBounds();
        for (JComponent nonPassable : collidableStuff) {
            // Because I didn't test the code, I'm covering all bases
            Rectangle nonPassableBounds = nonPassable.getBounds();
            if (nonPassableBounds.contains(playerBounds) || playerBounds.contains(nonPassableBounds) 
                            || playerBounds.intersects(nonPassableBounds) || nonPassableBounds.intersects(playerBounds)) {
                // Smack, we have a collision
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This example moves the responsibility of the creation of the objects to the constructor, rather the then the `go` method, which, frankly shouldn't exist - the `GamePane` shouldn't care about "how" it's been shown, that's not it's responsibility

Comment: Can i create an array holding the panels and call them in the loop

Comment: and then i can call the index for them

Comment: this is what i was trying to ask but i dont know why i didnt ask

Comment: @j.doe Why?  `ArrayList` is a dynamic array which supports (as does array) the enhanced `for-loop`